# how to split excel file if rows are above 64k using apache-poi?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am creating excel file using below code

```
public class ResultSetToExcel {
        private HSSFWorkbook workbook;
        private HSSFSheet sheet;
        private HSSFFont boldFont;
        private HSSFDataFormat format;
        private ResultSet resultSet;
        private FormatType[] formatTypes;

        public ResultSetToExcel(ResultSet resultSet, FormatType[] formatTypes, String sheetName) {
            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            this.resultSet = resultSet;
            sheet = workbook.createSheet(sheetName);
            boldFont = workbook.createFont();
            boldFont.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
            format = workbook.createDataFormat();
            this.formatTypes = formatTypes;
        }

        public ResultSetToExcel(ResultSet resultSet, String sheetName) {
            this(resultSet, null, sheetName);
        }

        private FormatType getFormatType(Class _class) {
            if (_class == Integer.class || _class == Long.class) {
                return FormatType.INTEGER;
            } else if (_class == Float.class || _class == Double.class) {
                return FormatType.FLOAT;
            } else if (_class == Timestamp.class || _class == java.sql.Date.class) {
                return FormatType.DATE;
            } else {
                return FormatType.TEXT;
            }
        }

        public void generate(OutputStream outputStream) throws Exception {
            try {
                ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
                if (formatTypes != null && formatTypes.length != resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount()) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Number of types is not identical to number of resultset columns. "
                            + "Number of types: " + formatTypes.length + ". Number of columns: "
                            + resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount());
                }
                int currentRow = 0;
                HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(currentRow);
                int numCols = resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount();
                boolean isAutoDecideFormatTypes;
                if (isAutoDecideFormatTypes = (formatTypes == null)) {
                    formatTypes = new FormatType[numCols];
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
                    String title = resultSetMetaData.getColumnName(i + 1);
                    writeCell(row, i, title, FormatType.TEXT, boldFont);
                    if (isAutoDecideFormatTypes) {
                        Class _class = Class.forName(resultSetMetaData.getColumnClassName(i + 1));
                        formatTypes[i] = getFormatType(_class);
                    }
                }

                currentRow++; // Write report rows
                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    row = sheet.createRow(currentRow++);
                    for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
                        Object value = resultSet.getObject(i + 1);
                        writeCell(row, i, value, formatTypes[i]);
                    }
                }
                // Autosize columns
                for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
                    sheet.autoSizeColumn((short) i);
                }
                workbook.write(outputStream);
            } finally {
                outputStream.close();
            }
        }

        public void generate(File file) throws Exception {
            generate(new FileOutputStream(file));
        }

        private void writeCell(HSSFRow row, int col, Object value, FormatType formatType) throws NestableException {
            writeCell(row, col, value, formatType, null, null);
        }

        private void writeCell(HSSFRow row, int col, Object value, FormatType formatType, HSSFFont font)
                throws NestableException {
            writeCell(row, col, value, formatType, null, font);
        }

        private void writeCell(HSSFRow row, int col, Object value, FormatType formatType, Short bgColor, HSSFFont font)
                throws NestableException {
            HSSFCell cell = HSSFCellUtil.createCell(row, col, null);
            if (value == null) {
                return;
            }
            if (font != null) {
                HSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
                style.setFont(font);
                cell.setCellStyle(style);
            }
            switch (formatType) {
            case TEXT:
                cell.setCellValue(value.toString());
                break;
            case INTEGER:
                cell.setCellValue(((Number) value).intValue());
                HSSFCellUtil.setCellStyleProperty(cell, workbook, HSSFCellUtil.DATA_FORMAT, HSSFDataFormat
                        .getBuiltinFormat(("#,##0")));
                break;
            case FLOAT:
                cell.setCellValue(((Number) value).doubleValue());
                HSSFCellUtil.setCellStyleProperty(cell, workbook, HSSFCellUtil.DATA_FORMAT, HSSFDataFormat
                        .getBuiltinFormat(("#,##0.00")));

                break;
            case DATE:
                cell.setCellValue((Timestamp) value);
                HSSFCellUtil.setCellStyleProperty(cell, workbook, HSSFCellUtil.DATA_FORMAT, HSSFDataFormat
                        .getBuiltinFormat(("m/d/yy")));
                break;
            case MONEY:
                cell.setCellValue(((Number) value).intValue());
                HSSFCellUtil.setCellStyleProperty(cell, workbook, HSSFCellUtil.DATA_FORMAT, format
                        .getFormat("($#,##0.00);($#,##0.00)"));
                break;
            case PERCENTAGE:
                cell.setCellValue(((Number) value).doubleValue());
                HSSFCellUtil.setCellStyleProperty(cell, workbook, HSSFCellUtil.DATA_FORMAT, HSSFDataFormat
                        .getBuiltinFormat("0.00%"));
            }
            if (bgColor != null) {
                HSSFCellUtil.setCellStyleProperty(cell, workbook, HSSFCellUtil.FILL_FOREGROUND_COLOR, bgColor);
                HSSFCellUtil
                        .setCellStyleProperty(cell, workbook, HSSFCellUtil.FILL_PATTERN, HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
            }
        }

        public enum FormatType {
            TEXT, INTEGER, FLOAT, DATE, MONEY, PERCENTAGE
        }
    }
```

And class implementing the above code

```
ResultSetToExcel resultSetToExcel = new ResultSetToExcel(rs,        new ResultSetToExcel.FormatType[] { ResultSetToExcel.FormatType.TEXT, ResultSetToExcel.FormatType.TEXT,            ResultSetToExcel.FormatType.INTEGER, ResultSetToExcel.FormatType.MONEY }, "Employee List");    resultSetToExcel.generate(new File("c:\\employees.xls"));
```

How to split the excel files if the records are above 64000 rows?

Edit:

How can I get the row count of excel sheet in POI ?
and if it is 64k how to create new excel?

How to get row counts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you modify your generate method as follows:

a) Make sure it generates no more than 64000 rows in one spreadsheet.

b) Have it return a boolean -- true if there are no more rows remaining in the ResultSet, false otherwise.

So, your main loop in the generate method might look something like this:

```
boolean allRowsDone = true;              
currentRow++; 
while (resultSet.next()) {
    row = sheet.createRow(currentRow++); 
    for (int i = 0; i < numCols; i++) { 
        Object value = resultSet.getObject(i + 1); 
        writeCell(row, i, value, formatTypes[i]); 
     }
     if (currentRow >= 64000) {
         allRowsDone = false;
         break; 
}
// put the rest of your code here
return allRowsDone;
```

Then, in the calling program you could do something like the following:

```
String baseFile = "c:\\employees";
String fileName = baseFile + ".xls";
int fileCount = 1;
while (true) {
    boolean done = resultSetToExcel.generate(new File(fileName));
    if (done) break;
    fileName = baseFile + "_" + fileCount + ".xls";
    fileCount++;
}
```

This would result in your creating as many excel files as needed, each excel file containing no more than 64000 rows. The first file is named "employees.xls", the second is named "employees_1.xls", and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

there is a method that gives the value from nth row if (valueOf(64000))column is not null create an another excell

Comment: can ypu please share the link ,where can i get that method?..and the method is of poi or resultset?